# Video as a source for the canvas drawImage() method is supported on Android?

Tags: android, cordova, video, canvas, drawimage

do you know if the video as a source for the canvas drawImage() method is supported on Android?

The goal is to display the video and to select one moment to take a picture of this moment in a frame (drawImage (video,0,0), return canvas)). Do you think it is doable?

Thanks!

Comment: Draw a video as an image? What would that look like? Draw the first frame? That would be an extreme waste of memory.

Comment: The goal is to display the video and to select one moment to take a picture of this moment in a frame (drawImage (video,0,0), return canvas)). Do you think it is doable?

Comment: Not sure. But you should add this to your question by editing it! Useful information.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. In fact when I am using my code on my laptop browser, it is working well. But on my android browser, I have nothing. On my android browser, I can take of "picture" of another image but not of a video. I don't know if there is something special to do for the video? maybe the format mp4 is the issue?

Comment: As of today, there's another issue which prevents from drawing the video onto the canvas: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=501208

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach in Android that will return you a bitmap for a given point in a video, which may give you want you need (or needed as this is an old question!):

MediaMetadataRetriever (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29)

> getFrameAtTime
>
> Added in API level 10
>
> Bitmap getFrameAtTime (long timeUs, 
>                   int option)
>
> Call this method after setDataSource(). This method finds a representative frame close to the given time position by considering the given option if possible, and returns it as a bitmap. This is useful for generating a thumbnail for an input data source or just obtain and display a frame at the given time position.